# how to check all and toggle at the same time

Tags: jquery

I have some checkboxes that toggle (show and hide) content. They work fine. But then when I add a check all checkbox, it checks all of them but the content no longer toggles. I'm confused on why and how to get this to work.

my html:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" class="section-select one">one </p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="section-select two">two</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="section-select three">three</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="check-all">check all</p>
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
```

my js:

```
$("input.check-all").change(function(){
    $("input.section-select").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
})

$("input.section-select").change(function(){
    var inputClass = $(this).attr("class").split(' ').pop();
    var sectionToHide = "#" + inputClass;
    $(sectionToHide).toggle();
});
```

Heres a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jawxvc49/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trigger()` to fire the change event.

```
$("input.check-all").change(function(){
    $("input.section-select").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
})
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks!